# How to accept all names with spaces and special characters in Google Dialogflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I have a `Dialogflow` chatbot which needs to create new users.
Dialogflow behaves unpredictably with non-Western names and especially those with spaces (`Anita Das`). It may or may not accept the word after the space.
Even `Anita-Das` is changed to `Anita-`.

How do I fix this?

I need Dialogflow to accept the user first name and last name separately as provided without removing any words.

I'm currently using `@sys.person` entity to identify names. Although, it accepts the given input 8/10 times, can I make it robust to always accept it every time? Even if I make it `@sys.any`, I run into similar issues.

User Input:

```
First name - Anita Sam
Last name - Jane-Hopper
```

Expected Dialogflow output:

```
First name - Anita Sam
Last name - Jane-Hopper
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should configure parameters for `@sys.person` as list (tick "Is List" on "Action in Parameters" configuration in Dialogflow UI).

Using "Training Phrases" you can learn agent to get all values separately. Than the API will respond with list of all strings for "First name" - something like (this is from my testing agent):

```
[ 
    { "name": "Anita" },
    { "name": "Sam" } 
]
```

that you can connect in your code as you need. Please check [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-actions-parameters#lists) for this feature.

Comment: I tried, but right now @sys.person is the closest solution to the problem. 8/10 times it will accept the names with spaces and common special characters.

Comment: Have you tried to use this list?